# About simulating an ac circuit in Pspice

Tags: ac, simulation, pspice, phasor

Firstly, It's not homework. I already know the answer. But I couldn't see sinusoidal waves to calculate phase of voltage(V0) across the capacitor. Response of capacitor is look like damping. However, the circuit is not first or second order circuit. In addition to this, (-j12 ohm)= 0.084F is correct?
(The answer is 41.60V)

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Picture response is "frequency analysis". What you want see is "transient analysis".

Comment: Is your question how to use Pspice? How did you calculate 41.60? That *is* correct, and you're a short step away from finding the phase angle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But I couldn't see sinusoidal waves to calculate phase of voltage(V0) across the capacitor.

The AC analysis doesn't give you the time domain response. If you want the time domain response, you should do a transient analysis.

But in this case, the AC analysis is actually better. It will give you the phasor of the response across a range of frequencies from a single simulation run, rather than requiring a separate run for each frequency. That single simulation run will probably also be significantly faster than a transient run.

If you want to see the phase angle of the voltage across the capacitor, just plot the phase of the `V(C6)` phasor instead of its amplitude. Unfortunately the details of how to do that are specific to PSpice, which I'm not familiar with. But when you plot the phase, you will be able to simply read the phase of the plot rather than trying to compare two sine waves in a time domain plot, so it will be much more accurate.

> However, the circuit is not first or second order circuit.

It has one energy storage element. Therefore it is a first-order circuit.

> In addition to this, (-j12 ohm)= 0.084F is correct? (The answer is 41.60V)

You haven't specified an operating frequency, so nobody can answer this question for you.

That said, if you know the reactance of the capacitor, you don't even need to know the operating frequency to solve the problem. Also, the fact that reactance was provided instead of capacitance means you weren't meant to use a simulation to solve the problem either.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are looking for a transient simulation, instead of the AC frequency sweep simulation that you ran instead. Alternatively, these problems usually specify a single frequency, but you put in a wise range of frequencies.

For reference, the three main types of simulation are DC, AC, and TRANsient.

- DC simulations show DC steady-state simulations, with a circuit parameter as the X-axis.
- AC simulations show the linearized AC gain across a range of frequencies. Frequency is the parameter on the X-axis.
- TRANsient simulations perform a time stepped evaluation of the circuit. Time is the parameter on the X-axis.